# first column in row won't style like the others

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Even though I have the same styling applied and there are 0 typing errors I still don't have my first column being style correctly. It just ends up being nothing but text inside a column square.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <!--Nav Bar-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col nav-bar-items">Home</div>
      <div class="col nav-bar-items">About</div>
      <div class="col nav-bar-items">Projects</div>
      <div class="col icon-items">
        <a class="icon-linkedin social-button borderless" href="http://linkedin.com/in/robert-renecker-85a561b8"></a></div>
      <div class="col icon-items">
        <a class="icon-github social-button borderless"href="http://github.com/robertrenecker"></a></div>
      <div class="col nav-bar-items">Contact</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col + .nav-bar-items{
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  color: #99ebff;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #99ebff;

  border-right: solid 5px black;
}
.col + .nav-bar-items:hover{
  background-color: #99ebff;
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  color:black;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `+` operator from your CSS that you have listed here.

`.col + .nav-bar-items` will select any `.nav-bar-items` that are immediately after a `.col` which is why the first one is being skipped.

`.col.nav-bar-items` will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
.col.nav-bar-items{
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  color: #99ebff;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #99ebff;

  border-right: solid 5px black;
}
.col.nav-bar-items:hover{
  background-color: #99ebff;
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  color:black;
}
```

because `+` will select next elem